# How to enlarge the size of facet in R

Tags: r

I'm working on the following dataset where each facet shows the bleaching for one kind of coral at one site across the time period. My problem is how to enlarge the size of each facet to see the trend more clearly, as in current facets, it is hard to see the trend because of the small change in bleaching....

here is my code,

```
cb1<-aggregate(cb$latitude, list(Site=cb$site), mean)
cb$site=factor(cb$site, levels=cb1$Site[order(cb1$x)])

ggplot(cb,aes(year,bleaching)) + 
 geom_point() +
 facet_grid(site~kind) +
 geom_smooth(method="lm",color="grey") + 
 coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))
```

[image]
due to the current size of the grid of facets, some lines seem flat but actually they are not.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. Try `facet_grid(site~kind, scales = "free_y")`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really increase the sizes of the facets unless you increases the size of the plot overall. One option would be to save a large version of the plot:

```
p<-ggplot(cb,aes(year,bleaching))+geom_point()+facet_grid(site~kind)+geom_smooth(method="lm",color="grey")+coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1))
ggsave("file_name.jpg", plot = p, width = 24, height = 24, units = "in")
```

If you have limited space (e.g. the plot has to go on an A4 sheet) then the `facet_grid_paginate` function from `ggforce` would be a good option. It allows you to split faceted plots over multiple pages. You can define the number of rows and columns per page. See [this](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggforce/man/facet_grid_paginate.html) link.

Alternatively, if you want to show that the lines are not flat more clearly, you can try toying with a couple of the arguments to `facet_grid`. `facet_grid` allows you to set the `scales` to `free`, `free_x` or `free_y`. Setting `free_y` would mean that each facet has its own y-axis (not necessarily between 0 and one (assuming you also removed the `ylim=c(0,1)`. This would, however, make the the facets more difficult to compare with each other.

Comment: thx for your kind reply! but I do not need to save it as jpg.....what i need is to show the trend clearly....

Comment: It's difficult without a reproducible example but scaling down the plot area horizontally would make the individual facets more square which would make it easier to see trends. Alternatively, you could try the paginated version of facet grid as I suggested but then you would require multiple images. Or, as @aelwan and I suggested, you could free the y-axes. so that each facet only displays the minimum required y range.